# Transferring among different assets under the same account

Tags: stellar-core, assets, stellar-sdk

Lets say ive an account with 2 assets USD, GBP and native asset as well. Can i transfer between USD and GBP belonging to same account ? Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just make a [path payment](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#path-payment) to yourself, from one asset to another.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help